# Get form field label in view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

After validatin and saving a form, is there any way to get field label text?
I try:

```
for field in form:
    print field.label
```

But I get:

> django.utils.functional.**proxy** object at 0x2557f90

Any solution for that?

SOLVED:
According to [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings) I need to call it in unicode() :

```
unicode(field.label)
```

Comment: Post your answer and accept it: this will get you points and close the question.